# Is it possible to run @Test testNG annotation multiple times with a different @BeforeMethod each time?

Tags: testng

I have 3 methods ("setup1","setup2", "setup3") and I'm using @BeforeMethod annotation on each one. Each method does something different and I want to run method Test1() 3 times, each time with a different @BeforeMethod method(e.g.: run1: setup1()>>Test1(), run2: setup2()>>Test1(), run3: setup3()>>Test1()). Is that possible?

This is my code:

```
@BeforeMethod
public void setup1() {
    //do something
}

@BeforeMethod 
public void setup2() {
    //do something else
}

@BeforeMethod 
public void setup3() {
    //do something else
}    

@Test
public void Test1() {
    //do something    
}
```

I've tried using dependsOnMethods{} inside @Test:

```
@Test(dependsOnMethods = {"setup1","setup2", "setup3"})
    public void Test1(){
    //do something
}
```

but this approach doesn't work because it will run all 3 @BeforeMethods at once before getting to Test1() and what I'd like to accomplish is running setup1()>>Test1(), run setup2()>>Test1() and finally run setup3()>>Test1().

Comment: could you specify what each of the beforeMethod does? or Is it possible to do those 3 different things in a dataprovider and pass the result to the test method as each test case?

Comment: Each BeforeMethod will login a user with different user/pass credentials and the Test method will do the same thing for each user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a data provider method, and inside it you could create 3 different users and pass it to the test method. So the test method would be invoked for each user.

```
@Test(dataProvider = "users")
public void Test1(User user) {
    //do something with user   
}

@DataProvider
public Object[][] users(){
   User user1 = null; //replace the null with code to create user1
   User user2 = null; //replace the null with code to create user2
   User user3 = null; //replace the null with code to create user3
   return new Object[][]{{user1},{user2},{user3}};
}
```

I don't think similar implementation could be done using `@BeforeMethod`

Comment: Thank you for the guidance.